# How add two recyclerview same fragmnets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Hi am going to add two `RecyclerView` same `fragment` as shown in image [image: as shown in image] but i have already did first recyclerview [image: click here to view implemnted] . I am not getting how to add one more with my existing code please help me. My `RecyclerView` code

**Communication.class**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_communication_summary, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.comm_expected_recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mRecyclerViewLayoutManager);

private class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<CommunicationVO>  mCommunicationVOsList;

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<CommunicationVO> communicationVOsList) {

        mCommunicationVOsList = communicationVOsList;
    }

@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.communication_summary_list_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder != null) {

            CommunicationVO communicationVO = mCommunicationVOsList.get(position);

            holder.expInvoiceNumber.setText(communicationVO.getExpInvoiceNumber());
            holder.expAmount.setText(CashPunditUtils.formatAmount(communicationVO.getExpAmount()));
            holder.expDueDate.setText(CashPunditUtils.formatDate(CashPunditUtils.extractDateAndTime(communicationVO.getExpDueDate()), "dd-MMM-yy"));
            holder.expPromisedDate.setText(CashPunditUtils.formatDate(CashPunditUtils.extractDateAndTime(communicationVO.getExpPromisedDate()), "dd-MMM-yy"));

        }
    }
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCommunicationVOsList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView expInvoiceNumber, expAmount, expDueDate, expPromisedDate;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            expInvoiceNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_invnum);
            expAmount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_amount);
            expDueDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_duedate);
            expPromisedDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_promisedate);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recycler_two"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in your Java code create two different instances of the same adapter and set that adapter to both recycler views.Since you have same view and different data you can use same adapter for both recycler view.Hope this helps you.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_communication_summary, container, false);


    //RecyclerView One
    mRecyclerView1 = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_one);
    mRecyclerView1.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter1 = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(communicationVOsList);
    mRecyclerViewLayoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView1.setLayoutManager(mRecyclerViewLayoutManager1);
    mRecyclerView1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    //RecyclerView  two
    mRecyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_two);
    adapter2 = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(communicationVOsList);
    mRecyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerViewLayoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView2.setLayoutManager(mRecyclerViewLayoutManager2);
    mRecyclerView2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    private class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private List<CommunicationVO>  mCommunicationVOsList;
        public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<CommunicationVO> communicationVOsList) {
            mCommunicationVOsList = communicationVOsList;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.communication_summary_list_item, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            if (holder != null) {

                CommunicationVO communicationVO = mCommunicationVOsList.get(position);
                holder.expInvoiceNumber.setText(communicationVO.getExpInvoiceNumber());
                holder.expAmount.setText(CashPunditUtils.formatAmount(communicationVO.getExpAmount()));
                holder.expDueDate.setText(CashPunditUtils.formatDate(CashPunditUtils.extractDateAndTime(communicationVO.getExpDueDate()), "dd-MMM-yy"));
                holder.expPromisedDate.setText(CashPunditUtils.formatDate(CashPunditUtils.extractDateAndTime(communicationVO.getExpPromisedDate()), "dd-MMM-yy"));

            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mCommunicationVOsList.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView expInvoiceNumber, expAmount, expDueDate, expPromisedDate;
            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                expInvoiceNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_invnum);
                expAmount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_amount);
                expDueDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_duedate);
                expPromisedDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_promisedate);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**:

Don't forget to create adapter object in recyclerview. Add these lines of code and try once.

```
mRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(mCommunicationVOsList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

Comment: No i have already added in xml one more  RecyclerView but i want how to fill one more RecyclerView

Comment: Dude he is making you code for free, thats really not encouraged here.

Comment: I don’t think so..But whatever...but it help other people who come across similar situations.

Comment: @rakeshKadadhi you can use the technique as the Solution provided to you

Comment: No its not coming only one recycler is filling.

Comment: i need to change anything in onCreateViewHolder

Comment: Dude you haven’t created adapter object only..how you expect to get recycler items?

Comment: i am giving both recycler view same data for testing. please can you show me

Comment: only one is filling i have tried. please check once

Comment: Accepted and rejected?why?

Comment: sorry for that, two recyclerview  is loading but i need different layout for both.

Comment: @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.communication_history_list_item, parent, false);

            View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.communication_summary_list_item, parent, false);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            ViewHolder viewHolder1 = new ViewHolder(view1);

            return viewHolder;
        }

Comment: You cannot show two different view holders for different layouts..If you have different item types then you can have different layout and view holder in an adapter..In case your both recycler views have different layout create different adapters and use them.